# Azure DevOps REST API, Authentication not working for build(s), yet for workitems it is

Tags: authentication, azure-devops-rest-api, unauthorized

I am trying to get the latest build-logs from azure devops with postman (as an example).
I have a accesstoken which I use to get all workitems and this works fine.
for example: 
`https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitemsbatch?api-version=5.1`

however, when I do the same for builds

`https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.1`

I am getting an 401 Unauthorized.

It's the same token from my App Registration.
My permissions is just the one:
https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/user_impersonation

What am I missing here?

Comment: I am having this same issue my PAT is working for GET/POST API through Postman, and also working for GET calls with Python code however, not working for POST calls through Python code.
I even tried with a PAT having full access but still getting 401.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't select full access when you create your token make sure either the Read or Read and Execute box under Build permissions is checked when you create the access token. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page

Comment: Thanks. So many tokens so many places to find the right place in azure is not my cup of tea.

Comment: Hi, were you able to find the solution for this ?